How can I get pretty icons for Google Docs files in GNOME's Google Drive integration?
In Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, with GNOME 46, I can use GNOME's "Online Accounts" feature to connect my Google account. I can then open Files (Nautilus) and see my Google Drive files and folders right there. I can see files of the type Google Docs, Google Sheets, Google Slides, Google Forms, and so on. When I double click one of these files, the document/spreadsheet/presentation is opened in my browser.
Here are what these files look like in Google Drive on my browser, with their pretty icons:

Here is what these files look like in Files (Nautilus):

As you can see, there are no beautiful icons for these files. This is especially confusing when there is no indication from the name of the file whether the file is a document, spreadsheet or presentation.
If I right-click on the file and click "Properties", I can see that the file has the correct mime-type:

application/vnd.google-apps.document type
application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet type
application/vnd.google-apps.presentation type

How do I make Files (Nautilus) display pretty icons for these types of files? I tried to install deepin-icon-theme, which seem to contain icons for these file types, but it didn't seem to have any effect.
